# How Can I Get Line Number in Visual Studio

Tags: numbers, line

I want to get line number from Visual Studio. Is it possible ? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CallerLineNumberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerlinenumberattribute.aspx)

```
public void DoProcessing()
{
    TraceMessage("Something happened.");
}

public void TraceMessage(string message,
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);
    Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
}

// Sample Output: 
//  message: Something happened. 
//  source line number: 31
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display line numbers in the IDE (as in your screenshot), follow these steps (tested in VS2012):

On the menu bar, choose **Tools / Options**. Expand the **Text Editor** node, then select either **All Languages** or, if you want it for just a specific language, open the node for the language you're using. Then check the **Line Numbers** checkbox in the **Display** section.

More info [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms165340%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood - your question is pretty ambiguous, especially with that screenshot.